# Compilation of std::make_shared on final subclass fails in type_traits::__is_empty1 using libcxx lib

Tags: c++11, gcc, android-5.0-lollipop, libc++

final_class is defined as :

```
class final_class final : private A {
public :
final_class() : A () {};
};
```

I am using final_class constructor as :

```
auto a = std::make_shared<final_class>();
```

And tring to compile using libcxx and `-std=c++11` fails to build with following error :

```
libcxx/include/type_traits:957:8: error: cannot derive from 'final' base 'final_class' in derived type 'std::__1::__is_empty1<final_class>'  struct __is_empty1
```

As I understand, It tries to derive from its parameters to determine whether or not a class is the virtual base of another class. 
Previously it worked before `final` introduction in C++.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I tried this (not on Android) and had no problems, with clang 5/6/7/8/9.  How old a clang version do you have?

Comment: @MarshallClow It should be Clang 3.4 or below as `__has_feature` appeared in 3.5. The problem can be observed on any Clang version by redefining `__has_feature`  https://godbolt.org/z/lfLt2R

Comment: @Nikita : Yup, it's Clang3.4.. Marshall, sorry for the delay!
What would be the fix, other than upgrading the toolchain itself?